# What phrasal verb or expression is used to say “make a short stop”?

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests, phrasal-verbs

So what I’m trying to say is “I made a short stop to buy coffee”, but in a more colloquial way. Is it okay to say “I stopped by to buy coffee? Or Like what would the correct expression be?

Comment: Trip the circuit breaker.

Comment: Turn someone into an Alex Rodriguez.

Comment: @HotLicks - You're usually spot on, but I don't understand either of those comments.

Comment: A "short circuit" is a failure in electrical wiring causing an excessive current flow.  The "circuit breaker" automatically "trips" to stop the short and prevent a fire or other damage.  And "shortstop" is a position in American baseball.  Alex Rodriguez is one of the better-known shortstops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasal verb *stop by* is generally used to mean [“to visit someone briefly.”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stop%20by) It seems you want to use it to mean a “short visit.” I would advise the following: If you say where you’re stopping by (i.e. the coffee shop), then you can fulfill the word’s definition. In other words, saying “I stopped **by the coffee shop** to get some coffee” would correlate with the definition “to visit someone briefly.” Even though you aren’t visiting someone per se, you are visiting *something* (a coffee shop). The main definition is, after all, “to visit [someone or something] briefly.” Truthfully, you can put anything in the brackets; the main idea is “to visit briefly.”

Also, if you leave out where you stopped by, it becomes ambiguous: Where did you stop by to get coffee? At your neighbor’s house? At the store? Saying where you stopped by removes any ambiguity.

[This may interest you as well...](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stop-by-in-off?q=stop%2Bby%252Fin%252Foff)

Comment: This is not about visiting anyone, though. It's about stopping off to do something.

Comment: @Lambie As I explained in my answer, the main part is visiting briefly. In reality, you can briefly visit anything: a park, a zoo, a store, etc. You can **stop by** a coffee shop just as easily as you can **stop by** someone’s house.

Comment: I think "visiting briefly" is not good as an explanation here, imo.  Yes, you can visit anything but here, I would not go for the word visit as a general thing.

Comment: @Lambie Take a look at this, if you please. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/us/amp/english/stop-by

Comment: Yes, it says at the hospital, doesn't it? If I were on my way to work and make a quick stop to buy coffee at a coffee place, I would not use: stop by. I would use: stop off.  "Stopping by" makes me think of houses, homes, places of work, apartments, hospitals, to see a person, yes,:)  And does not make me think of stopping off on my way to work at a restaurant or coffee shop to pick up coffee.

Comment: @Lambie I’d prefer not to argue, but what is the big difference?

Comment: This is Collins’s definition: “If you *stop by* somewhere, you make a short visit to a person or **place**.”

Comment: @Lambie So, I don’t see why *stop by* can’t apply to a restaurant or to a coffee shop but it can apply to every other **place**...

Comment: I give an opinion; you disagree; I explain giving my examples. And this is arguing? You have every right to disagree. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stop-off-somewhere I'll ***stop off at the shops*** on my way home and get some wine.
We're going to ***stop off in Denver*** for a couple of days before heading south. Yours is not wrong; I don't agree with the nuance.

Comment: @Lambie https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stop-by-in-off?q=stop%2Bby%252Fin%252Foff

Comment: Cambridge holds that all three prepositions are acceptable. So, we’re both right. :-)

Comment: It is not about right and wrong. It is about nuance of meaning.

Comment: @Lambie Well, all three prepositions (according to Cambridge) are considered equal, it seems. So, they’re synonymous.

Comment: You could use “by,” “in,” or “off”—they’re alike.

Comment: I’d comment that if you leave out where you stopped by, and context doesn’t immediately supply a place, the impression of the phrase would that you’re referring to *here*, where you’re currently standing/with whom you’re currently speaking. If someone told me they “stopped by to get coffee,” I’d expect they want to use my coffee machine...

Answer (score 7):

**I made a quick stop on my way to work to buy coffee.**

**A quick stop** is very used in American English.

We popped into [shop] to buy coffee. The Brits are always popping in and  into places, for this meaning.

the idiom is: a quick stop, not a short stop.

You drop by a neighbor's house.

> I'll ***stop off at the shops*** on my way home and get some wine.
>   We're going to stop off in Denver for a couple of days before heading
>   south.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stop-off-somewhere)

- I stopped by [your house or office] to you see you but you were out.
- I stopped off at the coffee shop to get coffee [**on my way to work**].
- I stopped in [to see you] but you were out.
- I stopped off to see you on my way home.
- I stopped off to buy gas and snacks and then resumed my trip to New York.

Phrasal: 
I swung by the coffee shop to get coffee.
**I stopped off to get coffee.**

Comment: "*The Brits are always popping in and into places*" :-) We **pop out** to the shops / to see a friend etc, as well.

Comment: @JamesRandom  :) Pop round, too. And I imagine pop up to another floor as well, in a tall building.  Crikey, if I could only get myself sorted....

Answer (score 5):

Alternatives are [dropped in and dropped by](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drop-by-in) as given by the Cambridge English dictionary. In British English both of these are more common than "stopped by". How common "dropped by" or "dropped in" are in American English I don't know.

Comment: drop by is very common in AmE, but here we do say make a quick stop [at a coffee shop].

Answer (score 3):

In American English, we'll commonly use a borrowed term from car racing, i.e. **"pit stop,"** to convey the brief stop you describe:

> "pit stop" - noun
>
> 1 : a stop at the pits during an automobile race
>
> 2 a (1) : a stop (as during a trip) for fuel, food, or rest or for use of a restroom

Assuming the listener is familiar at all with car racing, he/she will understand the reference to a stop which is as brief as possible and focused only on fulfilling certain essential needs.

Comment: "Here is a treat to make our minor prehistoric pit stop a bit more enjoyable." – *Bill and Ted* (It took seven hours for someone to suggest *pit stop* ? I wonder if it's becoming archaic... and why someone would DV this)

Comment: A pit stop is used for car trips. Not stopping off to get coffee on the way to the office....

Comment: @Lambie, I've used the term in just about any context.  E.g. friends at the office going out for lunch, as they walk out I'll say "I'll meet you in front, I need a quick pit stop" (as I head for the men's room).

Comment: Well, not for stopping for coffee, then. For a rest room on the highway, for example.

Comment: @Lambie - It's an American thing. Which, if you are, and y'all don't use it like that, I'd love to know where. A pit stop can be for absolutely anything, just so long as you, at the very least, plan to reembark.

Comment: Exactly @Mazura, it is very general -- can be used in multiple contexts, and can refer to multiple purposes for the stop.  In my case I'll use it most commonly in reference to a restroom visit because it's casual yet polite for a professional environment -- and personally I like it much better than the recent trendy term "bio-break."

Comment: @Mazura Yeah, well, I ain't interested in no pissin' contest. A pit stop is not used like this: On my way to work, I made a pit stop for coffee. Unless you have a weak bladder.  Compare that to: On our way to Buffalo from Chicago, we made several pits stops.  That said, you can use it as you like. The OP's definition even says:  "a stop (as during a trip)"

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for colloquial here in the Uk we would say

> stopped for a coffee

I can't guarantee this is any way correct english, but it is what I would say.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the sentence does not feel right is that (almost certainly) it contains a redundant word - buy. Furthermore, the unsettling presence of this word makes us doubt whether you had a drink of coffee on the premises, or were you perhaps buying some coffee beans for home consumption?
"I made a short stop for a coffee", or "I dropped/popped in for a coffee", or other formulations are quicker to say, sound perfectly idiomatic, and convey without reasonable doubt that you stopped for a short time, paid for and enjoyed drinking a cup of coffee, and then went on your way without let or hindrance.